# How to create WPF ComboBox with two aligned columns (and auto width for the first one)?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Turn this

[image: http://imgur.com/VZzMe6l]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNuzH.png)

Into this

[image]

Full description:

I was able to do it with this nasty hack (aggregating max column width needed):

```
// result.Type == typeof(List<MethodInfo>)
_returnTypeColumnWidth = result.Max(info => new FormattedText(info.ReturnType.Name, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, WindowsFlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch), FontSize, MediaBrushes.Black).Width);
```

and binding first control's (in a ComboBox.ItemTemplate) Width to it.

The question is: how to do it with MVVM?

My idea was to get MinWidth from a parent's property (which will be updated with Width changes):

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type sd:InvokeMethodDesigner}}, Path=ReturnTypeColumnWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type sd:InvokeMethodDesigner}}, Path=ReturnTypeColumnWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                Margin="0,0,4,0"
                TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding ReturnType.Name}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MethodInfoNameConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```
public double ReturnTypeColumnWidth
{
    get { return _returnTypeColumnWidth; }
    set
    {
        if(Double.IsNaN(value) || (value <= _returnTypeColumnWidth))
            return;
        _returnTypeColumnWidth = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ReturnTypeColumnWidth");
    }
}
```

But the ReturnTypeColumnWidth_set() is only called once, during TextBlock initialization (value is NaN).

Comment: Instead of `StackPanel` use `Grid` with defined 2 columns.

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  It means no business logic in the codebehind.  UI logic belongs there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get different `Grid`s to share column or row auto-sizing among themselves using the attached properties [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Grid.SharedSizeGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx). This does exactly what you're trying to do, but somebody else already wrote the code. If you had to write it yourself, I would recommend doing it with attached properties much like this -- or if you're in a real hurry, maybe even kludge it in the code behind. As Will notes in comments, this logic belongs entirely to the view. The less the viewmodel knows or cares about display column widths, the better.

```
<ComboBox
    ...
    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
    ...
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="Auto"
                        Grid.SharedSizeGroup="ReturnTypeNameColumn"
                        />
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="*"
                        />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="0,0,4,0"
                    TextAlignment="Right" 
                    Text="{Binding ReturnType.Name}"
                    />
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MethodInfoNameConverter}}" 
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

You might have to set `ItemsPanel` and put [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `StackPanel` you use for the items host, but try this first and see how it goes.